# jQuery filter() - filtering on multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-selectors

I want to filter based on two attributes, the first is id and the second is called level

i.e. id="someId" level="someLevel"

Shouldn't this code do the trick  ... it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(".someClass").filter("#"+id, "[level='"+level+"']").someAction();
```

Comment: Btw: I want to do the equivalent of an SQL AND statement not an OR statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing two arguments:

```
.filter("#someId", "[level='someLevel']")
```

You probably want this:

```
.filter("#someId[level=someLevel]")
```

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
$(".someClass").filter("filter1").filter("filter2")
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) in your filter function.

Answer (score 0):

If its an **or** condition you should really have a helper [function like string format](http://frogsbrain.wordpress.com/2007/04/28/javascript-stringformat-method/):

```
string.Format = function( text )
{
    //check if there are two arguments in the arguments list
    if ( arguments.length <= 1 )
    {
        //if there are not 2 or more arguments there’s nothing to replace
        //just return the original text
        return text;
    }
    //decrement to move to the second argument in the array
    var tokenCount = arguments.length - 2;
    for( var token = 0; token <= tokenCount; token++ )
    {
        //iterate through the tokens and replace their placeholders from the original text in order
        text = text.replace( new RegExp( "\\{" + token + "\\}", "gi" ),
                                                arguments[ token + 1 ] );
    }
    return text;
};
```

and then its easy:

```
var filter = string.format("#{0}, [level='{1}']", id, level);
$(".someClass").filter(filter).someAction();
```